# My app crashes when there is no value in my JSON

Tags: android

I'm posting "id" value (which i pass to this activity via getintent)

```
Uid = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

to server and retrieving the corresponding jsonobjects.

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", Uid);
            return params;
        }
```

When my jsonarray is empty, my app crashes. I want to toast"Error" when jsonarray is empty. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
public class kill extends FragmentActivity {
GridView grid1;
CustomGrid_Album adapter;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String Uid,Disp;
public String category;
public String selected;
public static String imagename;
Button Alb_sel;
ArrayList<Item_album> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item_album>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.album_display);

    grid1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
    Uid = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    Disp = getIntent().getStringExtra("disp");

    Alb_sel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.album_to_select);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(kill.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    //fetching JSONArray

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_Gallery4,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Datas.imageIds = new String[response.length()];
                    JSONArray arr = null;

                    try {
                        arr = new JSONArray(response);

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int i=0;

                    for (i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                            category = obj.getString("category_name");
                            selected = obj.getString("album_id");
                            imagename  = obj.getString("org_image_name");

                            Datas.imageIds[i] = AppConfig.URL_IMAGE_temp+obj.getString("album_image").substring(3);

                            gridArray.add(new Item_album(Datas.imageIds[i]));


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    final int xl = i;
                    adapter = new CustomGrid_Album(kill.this,xl,gridArray);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    grid1.setAdapter(adapter);
                    pDialog.dismiss();


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No images in this gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();

        }

    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", Uid);
            return params;
        }

    };

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}


}
```

Comment: Where is the error? `getString` or access one of the arrays?

Answer (score 1):

apply the check in **onResponse**

```
if(response.length()==0){
// error message
}else{
// your rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks problematic.

```
Datas.imageIds = new String[response.length()];
```

You don't want an array with the size of the string. You want an array of the size of the JSONArray **within the response**.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
    JSONArray arr = null;

    try {
        arr = new JSONArray(response);
        Datas.imageIds = new String[arr.length()];
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, your code is going to continue on if an exception is thrown there, then you'll end up with a NullPointerException, so you should move the for-loop into the `try-catch` as well.

Realistically, though, you should just use a `JSONArrayRequest` if you're going to be expecting a `JSONArray`.

> i want to toast"Error" when jsonarray is empty

Simple enough.

```
arr = new JSONArray(response);
if (arr.length() == 0) {
    // TODO: Toast
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add two checks to your onResponse method:

```
...

public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Check if the response itself is an empty string or null
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(response)) {
        // Show your user feedback
        return;
    }

    Datas.imageIds = new String[response.length()];
    JSONArray arr = null;

    try {
        arr = new JSONArray(response);

        // Check if your JSON has no elements in it
        if(arr.length == 0) {
            // Show your user feedback
            return;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    ...
```

Comment: It crashes? What exactly is your stacktrace?

Comment: I mean in your logcat. - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `JSONArray arr = null;`

After that you assign the server's JSON to that JSONArray.

Add a line after getting that

```
if(arr==null)
{
 //toast
}
else
{
//whatever you want to do with JSON
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_Gallery4,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                if(response.length()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"no data found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{                   
                            Datas.imageIds = new String[response.length()];
                            JSONArray arr = null;

                            try {
                                arr = new JSONArray(response);

                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        if(arr.length()>0){
                            int i=0;

                            for (i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    category = obj.getString("category_name");
                                    selected = obj.getString("album_id");
                                    imagename  = obj.getString("org_image_name");

                                    Datas.imageIds[i] = AppConfig.URL_IMAGE_temp+obj.getString("album_image").substring(3);

                                    gridArray.add(new Item_album(Datas.imageIds[i]));


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            final int xl = i;
                            adapter = new CustomGrid_Album(kill.this,xl,gridArray);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            grid1.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"no data found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }



                    pDialog.dismiss();


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No images in this gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();

        }

    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", Uid);
            return params;
        }

    };
```

Comment: `adapter = new CustomGrid_Album(kill.this,xl,gridArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to check whether response is null or not and in object check whether it is having key or data with key is not null

```
if(response!=null){

   try {
   Datas.imageIds = new String[response.length()];
   JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
      try {
               JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
               if(obj!=null){
                  if(obj.has("category_name") && !obj.isNull("category_name"){
                      category = obj.getString("category_name");
                  }
                  if(obj.has("album_id") && !obj.isNull("album_id"){
                       selected = obj.getString("album_id");
                  }
                  if(obj.has("org_image_name") && !obj.isNull("org_image_name"){
                        imagename  = obj.getString("org_image_name");
                  }
                   if(obj.has("album_image") && !obj.isNull("album_image"){                     
                          Datas.imageIds[i] = AppConfig.URL_IMAGE_temp+obj.getString("album_image").substring(3);
                          gridArray.add(new Item_album(Datas.imageIds[i]));
                  }
           }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      final int xl = i;
      adapter = new CustomGrid_Album(kill.this,xl,gridArray);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      grid1.setAdapter(adapter);
      pDialog.dismiss();
} catch (JSONException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using StringRequest, instead of that use JsonArrayRequest to make request as below, so you will get response in onResponse methode when there is a valid JSONArray in response, and if there is no data then you will get response in onError method

JsonArrayRequest rReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,"url", new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.toString() );

```
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: "+error.getMessage() );
        }
    })
```